# How to make groovy script using "execute" portable?

Tags: groovy

I have a groovyscript which uses for examle

```
"mvn install".execute()
```

While this works very well on linux, this will fail on windows. On windows one would have to write:

```
"cmd /C mvn install".execute()
```

Which is somewhat anoying. I just want to avoid cluttering my code by using `if OS == windows then`. I am pretty sure someone has already solved this problem and provides some library for this. I just can not find anything ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `String.execute()` delegates to the operating system, it shouldn't be expected to be portable, but you can create your own portable-ish equivalent.

```
String.metaClass.pexecute = {
    if(/* Windows OS check goes here*/) {
        "cmd /C $delegate".execute()
    } else {
        delegate.execute()
    }
}
```

With this code placed early in the script you can call `String.pexecute()` like this: `"mvn install".pexecute()`